# Is there some way to define the number of decimal places for all operations in C++?

Tags: c++, precision

I'm writing a program to essentially simulate particle collision that, at several points, requires me to take the difference between two doubles. However, due to the way data is stored in a computer, this naturally leads to some errors. Those normally wouldn't be a problem, except a few of the verifications I need the difference for are to check if the difference is zero (i.e.: if the numbers are equal to one another).

I read about `setprecision()`, but that only works for streams. I need a way to truncate to X decimal places for every single operation, where X can be any number of decimal places. I was hoping there was a way to do this natively in C++, without me having to "brute-force" it (i.e.: multiply the doubles by 10^X, convert them to ints, do the operations and verifications, then divide the results by 10^X for the output, every single time), but I can't seem to find it.

Before I start going through hundreds of lines of code, I just wanted to be sure there's absolutely no built-in way to do this in C++.

TL;DR: Can I automatically truncate doubles to a certain number of decimal places in an entire program?

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/202446/discussion-on-question-by-orion-is-there-some-way-to-define-the-number-of-decima).

Comment: There is no required format standard for floating point in C++.  The precision is based on the size of the manitissa (if stored in sign, mantissa, exponent format).  For more accurate precision you may want to consider using Fixed Point with a Big Number library (e.g. 64 or 128 bit integers).